# Apache Beam - Pass a variable from previous step in Python

Tags: python, apache-beam

I am trying to build a simple pipeline processing a json. My Pipeline looks like this

```
input_files = 'message.json'

options = PipelineOptions()
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
    # reading json and fetching its contents
    lines = (
            p | 'Read JSON' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(input_files)
              | 'Fetch Data and File Name' >> beam.ParDo(FetchFileName('start'))
        )
    sdata = beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(lines['sdata'])
    transform = (
            lines
            | 'Parallel Transform of Data' >> beam.ParDo(AdjustObject(), service_id=sdata)
            | 'PRINT' >> beam.Map(print)
        )
```

And the FetchFileName looks like this

```
class FetchFileName(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self,element):
        element = json.loads(element)
        gdata = element['data']
        for elm in gdata:
            yield elm
        yield beam.pvalue.TaggedOutput('sdata', element['id'])
```

I am trying to pass the 'id = 999' value as a variable called 'sdata' to the next pipeline step called 'Parallel Transform of Data' but keep getting the following error

```
TypeError: 'PCollection' object is not subscriptable
```

My Json file looks like below

```
{"id":999,"data":[{"Emp_Id":495},{"Emp_Id":494}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code you have shared, the step `ParDo(FetchFileName('start'))` should produce two output PCollections:

1. The main output, containing each item in `element['gdata']` across all the JSON values in all the files.
2. The output `sdata` that contains the collection of `element['id']` across all the JSON values in all the files.

To produce these two PCollections you need to modify your `ParDo` with the `.with_outputs` method, like this:

```py
results = (
    p | 'Read JSON' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(input_files)
      | 'Fetch Data and File Name' >> beam.ParDo(FetchFileName('start').with_outputs(
          'sdata',
          main='gdata'))
```

So if the input files contained

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "gdata": ["a", "b", "c"]
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "gdata": ["q"]
}
{
  "id": 3,
  "gdata": ["y", "z"]
}
```

Then the output PCollections would be:

- `results['sdata']` would contain `1`, `2`, `3`
- `results['gdata']` would contain `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, `"q"`, `"x"`, `"y"`

See the full documentation at https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#additional-outputs.

Now I see another problem: the next line would probably not work as expected. Since the collection `results['sdata']` contains many values, you cannot apply `AsSingleton`. I do not know your full desired result, but I hope this helps to explain the first part to get you further toward your goal.

Comment: Hi Ken, Thanks a bunch!!! It's working now. In my case AsSingleton worked as I needed to pass only a single value as 'Id' from the main JSON file to the next Step ('Parallel Transform of Data')

Comment: Hi Ken, This side input solution works for me in Google Colab environment where I'm testing my code but doesn't seem to work on Google Dataflow, The data passes though all my pipeline steps but doesn't print it (it all works if I hardcode the value). Would you know whether Google Dataflow does or doesn't support dynamic Side inputs?

Comment: There is no Beam concept of "dynamic Side Inputs". A side input is a way to view the contents of a PCollection as a single value (per window). It may be that it works in the colab for "accidental" reasons, or because your data only has one element with an id.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I solved the passage of side input issue in google dataflow using the code from this medium article which recommended to cache the side input value first before passing it to next step https://medium.com/google-cloud/cache-reuse-across-dofns-in-beam-a34a926db848